# SQL query to generate summary file base on change in price per item

Tags: sql, summary

I need help writing a query to generate a summary file of quantity purchase per item, and per cost from a purchase history file.  To run the query the **ORDER BY** would be **ITEM_NO, PO_DATE, AND COST**.

**SAMPLE DATE - PURCHASE HISTORY**

[image]

**OUTPUT FILE - SUMMARY**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can group by `item_no` and `cost` and get all the info we need.

```
select    item_no
         ,cost
         ,min(po_date) as start_date
         ,max(po_date) as end_date
         ,sum(qty)     as qty

from     (
         select  *
                 ,count(chng) over(partition by item_no order by po_date) as grp
         from    (
                 select *
                       ,case when lag(cost) over(partition by item_no order by po_date) <> cost then 1 end as chng
                 from   t
                ) t
         ) t
group by item_no, cost, grp
order by item_no, start_date
```

| item_no | cost | start_date | end_date | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 1.25 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | 2021-01-04 00:00:00 | 150 |
| 12345 | 2.00 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00 | 2021-02-03 00:00:00 | 60 |
| 78945 | 5.25 | 2021-06-10 00:00:00 | 2021-06-12 00:00:00 | 90 |
| 78945 | 4.50 | 2021-10-18 00:00:00 | 2021-10-19 00:00:00 | 150 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5A-7jptv)

Comment: Yes, but it would not give me the correct result if the file is not sorted by ITEM_NO and PO_DATE.

Comment: DannySlor - I've tried your script, and it did not work.  Could I send you my sample data?

Comment: I've tried your script, but it did not work.  Could I send you my sample data, only 131 records?

Comment: @user3537446 send me a fiddle with it.

Comment: I was able to get it to work by adding the item_no to the order by in the over section "count(chng) over(order by item_no, po_date) as grp" - thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @user3537446 typo, see updated answer